# Looping in R using 2 sqlquerys

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to run a loop through R by calling a stored proc in SQL, running a regression, then putting the results into a table in SQL. The stored proc uses a parameter called DiagCd and if I input an individual DiagCd, it recognizes it and pulls in the related data. After it pull it in I have no problems running the regression and then inserting into the table. However once I try to run this for multiple DiagCds, it won't recognize the code being used.

I start with connecting to the Data Source

```
con <- odbcConnect("RViper", uid="jzinnel")
```

Then grab a list of the codes from a query

```
codes <- sqlQuery(con,"select distinct diagcd from Table where DiagPosition = 1")
```

Next I start the loop:

(use 4 just to see if I can get it to work without running through 7,000+ codes)

```
 for (i in 1:4)
{
  # Get DiagCd to for this iteration
  mDiagCd <- codes[i]

  # Get Data to run Regression on
  data<-sqlQuery(con, "R_DiagnosisCodes mDiagCd")

  # Run Regression
  Reg <- lm(Service~Zip+State+Gender+Age+Height+Weight,data)

  # Save Data
  estimate.table <- cbind("Estimate" = coef(Reg))
  DiagCd <- data$DiagCd[1]
  data1 <- data.frame(t(estimate.table <- cbind("Estimate" = coef(Reg))),row.names = DiagCd)
  sqlSave(con, data1, tablename='Table2', append = TRUE, rownames = 'DiagCd', colnames = FALSE)
}
```

I notice that the problems I get starts with bringing in the codes at the beginning. When I say codes$diagcd[1], it gives the value but then lists a function right after

> codes$diagcd[1]
>   [1]  191.1
>   7813 Levels: \177682.6  174.9  191.1  63012  709.2  788.9  806.8  836.1  V55.2 0 .. V90.89"

I am not sure if this means it cannot recognize which code to pull in or not. Also when pulling in "data". I am not sure if I am doing that right either. I just started using R last week so any tips or if further clarification is needed just let me know.

Comment: An `sqlQuery` line confuses me. Shall it be something like `data<-sqlQuery(con, sprintf("select R_DiagnosisCodes('%s')", mDiagCd)` if *mDiagCd* is a string?

Comment: I'm not sure. The [data<-sqlQuery(con, "R_DiagnosisCodes mDiagCd")] is pulling the stored proc. When I did a single code it was, as an example  [data<-sqlQuery(con, "R_DiagnosisCodes 869")] and it worked perfectly. it could have something to do with the mDiagCd tho so I will try what you wrote.

Comment: I don't know what sql dialect you are using, but as you wrote it *mDiagCd* is being passed as an unknown entity. Use sprintf like `data<-sqlQuery(con, sprintf("R_DiagnosisCodes %d", mDiagCd))`. P.S. Somehow there is a huge number of questions on SO about R mixing up variables names and their values.

Comment: When trying your suggestion, it didn't like the %d and gave other suggestions but when I found one that worked, it did make it through the loop but didn't give all the info from it. Going to try to tweek it a little.

Comment: @mlt thanks for the help. Turns out [data<-sqlQuery(con, sprintf("R_DiagnosisCodes %e", mDiagCd))] worked to make the loop go. I adjusted my codes variable to specify 3 specific codes. Now all I need to do is get the codes part working with the query as well unless I go through and just type all 7000+ in (copy and paste them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Setup Connection
con <- odbcConnect("name", uid="me")
conn <- odbcConnect("name", uid="me")
# Get all codes
codes2 <- sqlFetch(conn, "codes")
x <- sapply(codes2, is.factor)
codes2[x] <- lapply(codes2[x], as.character)

# Loop through codes 
for (i in 1:978)
{
  # Get DiagCd to for this iteration
  mDiagCd <- codes2$DiagCd[i]

  # Get Data to run Regression
  data<-sqlQuery(con, sprintf("storedproc%s", mDiagCd))

  # Run Regression
  Reg <- lm(TotalServiceDays~Zip+State+Gender+Age+Height+Weight,data)

  # Create to table
  estimate.table <- cbind("Estimate" = coef(Reg))
  DiagCd <- data$DiagCd[1]
  data1 <- data.frame(t(estimate.table <- cbind("Estimate" = coef(Reg))),row.namesDiagCd)
sqlSave(conn, data6, tablename='table', append = TRUE, rownames = 'DiagCd', colnames = FALSE)
}

#Close channels
odbcClose(con)
odbcClose(conn)
```